# Bibliography not appearing

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, texmaker, jabref

So, I created a library using Jabref. I saved the library in the same folder my texmaker file is located, however the bibliography doesn't appear at the end of the paper and I am having issues finding the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin={3cm},rmargin={2.5cm},
tmargin={2.5cm},bmargin = {2.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,lipsum}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small,labelsep=none]{caption}

\begin{document}
...
\newpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I get this kind of error too:

*Process started
INFO - This is Biber 2.18 INFO - Logfile is 'Titelblatt.blg' INFO - Reading 'Titelblatt.bcf' INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0 INFO - Processing section 0 INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'Literatur.bib' for section 0 INFO - LaTeX decoding ... INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'Literatur.bib' ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Temp\biber_tmp_mMmO\fe6d16e8a0935a16f008a64fa11444f8_20952.utf8, line 9, syntax error: found ",", expected one of: number, name (entry type, key, field, or macro name), end of entry ("}" or ")") or quoted string ({...} or "...") WARN - Invalid or undefined BibTeX entry key in file 'C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Temp\biber_tmp_mMmO\fe6d16e8a0935a16f008a64fa11444f8_20952.utf8', skipping ... INFO - WARNINGS: 1 INFO - ERRORS: 1
Process exited with error(s)*

**Here is my `Literatur.bib` code:**

```
@Book{Birgit,
  author    = {Birgit Bender},
  publisher = {Diplomica GmbH},
  title     = {Methoden zur Messung der Lichtgeschwindigkeit und Aspekte zur Konstanz der Lichtgeschwindigkeit},
  year      = {2000},
  address   = {Hamburg},
}

@Book{,
  author    = {Adolf Wüllner},
  publisher = {B. G. Treubner Verlag},
  title     = {Lehrbuch der Experimentalphysik},
  year      = {1883},
  address   = {Leipzig},
  series    = {zweiter Band},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

Comment: I just added biber %, but somehow I get the error, everytime I press F11: Process started

INFO - This is Biber 2.18 INFO - Logfile is 'Titelblatt.blg' INFO - Reading 'Titelblatt.bcf' INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0 INFO [...], skipping ... INFO - WARNINGS: 1 INFO - ERRORS: 1

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SE. Can you also add `Literatur.bib` because I tested your code with my bib file and it works without errors; it doesn't need to be the full content, though. Note, I added `\nocite{*}` before `printbiliography` to make sure all citations are included.

Comment: @Celdor I added `\nocite{*}` however the issue still proceeds. Please have a look at the error I mentioned in my quesiotn, every time I press F11 the error appears and no bibliography is generated. My `Literatur.bib`: @Book{Birgit,
  author    = {Birgit Bender},
  publisher = {Diplomica GmbH},
  title     = {Methoden zur Messung der Lichtgeschwindigkeit und Aspekte zur Konstanz der Lichtgeschwindigkeit},
  year      = {2000},
  address   = {Hamburg},
}
@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}

Comment: The `Literatur.bib` file cannot be parsed because there's a syntax error at line 9 and `Biber` which is used to process bibliography complains about it. Your `tex` file is OK.

Comment: Yes, thanks for taking the time to help! Problem solved :D

Comment: `\nocite{*}` is used in testing because all entries from `Lteratur.bib` are included in your `Bibliography` regardless of citations used in the document, so empty document will also produce full bibliography.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that I didn't add a **citationkey** to the second book listed in `Literatur.bib`. Just did that and that problem did get solved.